# Html encode decode in asp.net store and fetch

Tags: asp.net, xss, html-encode, htmldecode

I have a problem with restricting malicious content in a field which can accept any input from the user.

I have to encode that field and save it in the database - see examples:

**1st example**

`<space>` is saved as  `&lt;space&gt;`

**2nd example (malicious text)**

`"><svg/onload=prompt(1)>`
is saved as `&quot;&gt;&lt;svg/onload=prompt(1)&gt;`

Now in reports I have to decode that into actual text, but the second text is malicious script now. What should I do?

Is there any other way to stop malicious text  on both client and server side?

Comment: " I have to decode that into actual text,"...Do you? Why? Leave it encoded, problem solved. That was the whole point of encoding it in the first place. If you're just going to decode it again when you display it, you've defeated the entire purpose of adding this protection. Putting malicious HTML into a database isn't, in itself, a problem - databases don't care about HTML or script. It's only a problem when you come to re-display it again in a HTML document. Encoding it for storage, only to decode it again when retrieving it means you achieve nothing useful.

Comment: I agree with @ADyson . Save the text as it’s received and encode it before you serve it on the client site.

Comment: @crellee Glad you agree. One point though - it's going to be more efficient computation-wise to encode it once when it's received and stored, rather than having to repeatedly encode it every time it's displayed.

Comment: .. and you should always encode user input before you send it to other clients to prevent cross site scripting

Comment: so you all are suggest me if user save **<space>** then in report i will show him **&lt;space&gt;**

Comment: @crellee can you please help

Comment: Yes that will be it. In what kind of format you save the text is your decision. Like @ADyson said you will save some work for each request if you encode it before you store it in the database. But it’s still a matter of taste - I prefer to save the data as it is (unless I encrypt or hashes) so the data is easier to read and easier to access. So therefore for each request I will need to encode the text. But to answer your question; If you serve the text in HTML you MUST encode it first.

Comment: " if user save `<space>` then in report i will show him `&lt;space&gt;"`...yes, if the user entered invalid / junk data then they will get junk data in return. Garbage in, garbage out. It's the user's fault, surely? Or are you saying that `<space>` is an acceptable input and you want that to be treated as HTML and the browser should use it to render the content, rather than just printing it as plain text? If so then you need to have a whitelist of acceptable input values, and only encode those which are not considered valid.

Comment: Or you could have a blacklist of unacceptable one, but the downside of this is it's potentially less secure - you have to remember to update it as technology changes and more potentially problematic elements are created